# Running a script on each reboot of EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, command, startup

I am running an Amazon Linux EC2 instance. It is a node.js server. I need to run the following command on each reboot/startup:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080
```

The command above redirects port 80 to port 8080.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try this: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently

Comment: Also, why not change your node.js server to run on port 8080 instead?

Comment: It depends on which Linux distribution you use. This may help you [Run script on start up](http://superuser.com/questions/685471/how-can-i-run-a-command-after-boot)

Comment: @chedabob the node.js server does run on port 8080 but AWS has HTTP traffic on port 80

Comment: A have tried putting a bash script in /etc/init.d/ and chmoded it to be executable but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the issue by placing my script in the /etc/rc.local file

This file gets executed after all other init scripts which is what I needed.

Comment: you can not have access to root user. when you are in prod, it will solve the issue but will not fix it.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trials, below worked:

```
crontab -e
     @reboot cd /home/ec2-user/somedir/ && ./run.sh  > output1.txt

vi ./run.sh
     ./run2.sh 2>&1 > output2.txt &

./run2.sh
    # this had actual commands, it also had a nohup command
```

Comment: but this will work with root user not ec2-user , do you think you will have access to root use in prod

Comment: Right. Will the below answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30412538/984471